# What is the logic behind Cardano's tokenomics and emmission schedule?

Tags: inflation, supply

Bitcoin was made to be mined until roughly 2140.  I like that it was made for decades to come while many projects are built for 4 years or whatever.

Personally I do not believe inflation in and of itself is bad, as economies are not static and expand.  What is bad is inflation manipulation that is unprovable and not tamper-proof, or when it is too high.

Coin Gecko currently shows circ supply to TS as:

32,056,062,599 / 45,000,000,000

71% in circulation on the 3rd year already seems a bit high.

Does Cardano have to have a fixed supply?  A perpetual, provable, tamper-proof small stock-to-flow seems best to me.

Can someone make the decisions behind Cardano's inflation make sense to me?

Answer (score 4):

The uncirculated (reserve) coins are distributed over time at a specific percentage rate.  As the reserve decreases in size, the amount distributed each epoch (5 days) will decrease.  At the current percentage rate the reserve will halve approximately every 4-5 years.

- Ada has a fixed supply of 45 billion coins
- 30 Billion coins were issued/sold during the ICO rounds
- The other 15 Billion coins were placed into a reserve for operation of the network
- Every 5 days (each epoch) the transaction fees and a fixed percentage of the reserve are added to a pot
- A fixed percentage of the epoch's pot is added to the treasury and the rest are distributed as staking rewards

[Cardano monetary policy](https://docs.cardano.org/en/latest/explore-cardano/cardano-monetary-policy.html) has a more precise explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Eventually we will stop measuring Cardano in Ada and start measuring it in “Lovelace.”

Comment: I do not agree with that. Even with a 10 trillion market cap, one ADA will be worth something around 320$, which is still affordable.

Comment: Request add rationale for your statements. Short answers without adequate explanations get flagged as low-quality posts.